# Python detect aligned segments in a mesh

Tags: python, geometry, detection

I am searching for a method to detect the segments of a mesh that are approximately in line.

I have a set of `points` defined by their `x, y` coordinates:

[image: quasiperiodic set of points]

Then I perform a Delaunay triangulation:

[image: triangulated set]

As you can see, may elements of the mesh are forming quasi-lines. I would like to find a solid way to detect these quasi-lines...

I tried to define every segment of the mesh by a cartesian equation `y = m.x+b` and to parse the values `alpha = arctan(m)` (an angle) and `b`, with a threshold system, but I am getting poor results:

[image: detected lines]

What would be your strategy to detect a maximum of those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit every edge and (using the topological information that you have) find the edges that share an endpoint with it. Keep the ones that form the best alignment. If the alignment is within some tolerance, consider that these edges are linked.

After processing the whole triangulation, you will have as set of linked lists containing the alignments.

Comment: Thank you, what function would you use to characterize the alignment?

Comment: Compute the angle between the segments (resolve the triangle).