# Find aligned and nearly-aligned segments in a 2D triangular mesh

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, mesh

I have a cloud of 2D points with the structure `(x, y, index)`

example:

```
pts = [[0,0,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,3],[1,0,4],[1,1,5],[1,2,6],[2,0,7],[2,1,8],[2,2,9]]
```

and a series of segments with the structure `(index1, index2)`  that connect these points 2 by 2:

```
segs = [[1,2],[1,4],[1,5],[2,3],[2,5],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5],[4,7],[4,8],[5,6],[5,8],[5,9],[6,9],[7,8],[8,9]]
```

The segments always connect only two points, they never pass through a third point.

[image: segments]

How would I detect the aligned segments and make longer segments with `n` indices, when I should use the segments in `seg` only once?

```
aligned = [[1,2,3],[1,4,7],[1,5,9],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[3,5],[4,5,6],[4,8],[7,8,9]]
```

[image: longer segments]

Now say that the points are not perfectly aligned:

```
pts = [[0.002,0.1,1],[0.0003,1.003,2],[-0.01,2.11,3],[1.01,0.101,4],[1.0005,1.2,5],[1.25,2.01,6],[2.007,-0.12,7],[1.996,1.1,8],[2.03,2.1,9]]
```

[image: segments2]

I want to I connect nearly aligned segments if the angle between the segments is nearly null, defined by a `tolerance` of, for example, `3°`

I have tried many methods but I couldn't succeed. This has to be done on massive nets of 10k+ points.

This code recreates my examples:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#pts = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,3],[1,0,4],[1,1,5],[1,2,6],[2,0,7],[2,1,8],[2,2,9]])
pts = np.array([[0.002,0.1,1],[0.0003,1.003,2],[-0.01,2.11,3],[1.01,0.101,4],[1.0005,1.2,5],[1.25,2.01,6],[2.007,-0.12,7],[1.996,1.1,8],[2.03,2.1,9]])

indices = pts[:,2].astype(int)

seg = np.array([[1,2],[1,4],[1,5],[2,3],[2,5],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5],[4,7],[4,8],[5,6],[5,8],[5,9],[6,9],[7,8],[8,9]])

for s in seg:
    i1, i2 = s
    segment = np.array((pts[indices == i1][0], pts[indices == i2][0]))
    plt.plot(segment[:,0],segment[:,1],color="black")
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()

aligned = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,4,7],[1,5,9],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[3,5],[4,5,6],[4,8],[7,8,9]],dtype=object)

for a in aligned:
    p = []
    for index in a:
        p += [pts[indices == index][0]]
    p = np.array(p)
    print(p)
    plt.plot(p[:, 0], p[:, 1])

plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

NOTE: this question is formulated differently and more universally than my previous question here [Python detect aligned segments in a mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864667/python-detect-aligned-segments-in-a-mesh) I would appreciate that it is not considered a duplicate of it.

Comment: Is there a specific way you wish to tie-break if, say, 3 lines meet at a point in a Y-shape and there's more than one way to extend a segment?

Comment: I'd say random choice between strictly identical angles, and if the angles are different, then i'd go for the smallest

Comment: I am not sure about the computationally best solution for this problem, but if you are sure that in the pts array every index from 1 to n occurs exactly once, it is much better to start with sorting this array (if necessary) such that you can change the second line in your first for loop to "segment = np.array((pts[i1-1], pts[i2-1]))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with these general assumption that not necessarily all indices exist.

I would try an algorithm like this: (python/pseudocode)

```
point_dict = dictionary( index : point )
seg_set = set( seg )
seg_endpoints = dictionary( index of point : list of segments containing this point )

result = []
while not empty(seg_set):
    segment = seg_set.pop()
    result.append(segment)
    left, right = segment.left, segment.right
    # going to the left
    while True:
        possible_lefts = seg_endpoints[left]
        additional_left = get_line_to_left(possible_lefts)
        if additional_left is None:
            break
        remove_additional_left_from_seg_set()
        remove_additional_left_from_seg_endpoints()
        left = additional_left.left
        results[-1].prepend(left) # not real syntax offcource
    # going to the right
    while True:
        possible_rights = seg_endpoints[left]
        additional_right = get_line_to_right(possible_rights)
        if additional_right is None:
            break
        remove_additional_right_from_seg_set()
        remove_additional_right_from_seg_endpoints()
        left = additional_right.right
        results[-1].append(right) # this is real syntax :)
```

I left out a lot of implementation details, but since you mentioned you tried different methods without too much success I hope you can at least get some ideas from this algorithm.
One important implementation detail is how to store the segments in the seg_endpoints and how to delete a specific segment out of this one.

One possibility is to convert the segments to a dataclass and than you can link to these segments. Another is to keep track of where all these segments are with some extra indices.

In any case, for networks of tens of thousands of points I certainly think making these dictionaries will save your algorithm a lot of time.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I had in mind. I corrected a small mistake and finally succeedeed

Comment: If it is a mistake visible in the pseudocode, I would like to update my answer with your fix.

Comment: You psudocode is fine, mistake was on my side

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way to approach it.

In order to have some test cases, lets start with a code generating random graphs of the type described in the question. The function `generate_graph()` returns a tuple `(points, edges)`
where `points` is a list of tuples with coordinates of graph vertices, and `edges` is a list of tuples with indices of vertices that are connected by an edge. Graph vertices are evenly spaced in a grid with `nrow` rows and `ncol` columns. The argument `p` gives the probability that an edge connecting two adjacent vertices will be created. A higher value of `p` will give a graph with more edges. The `distortion` argument can be used to distort the grid of vertices.

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

def generate_graph(nrow, ncol, p=0.5, distortion=0):

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ncol), np.arange(nrow))
    if distortion:
        X  = X + np.random.random(X.shape)*distortion
        Y  = Y + np.random.random(Y.shape)*distortion
    pts = list(zip(X.ravel(), Y.ravel()))
    edges = []
    for i, j in product(range(nrow-1), range(ncol-1)):
        rands =  np.random.random(4)
        if rands[0] < p:
            edges.append(np.ravel_multi_index([[i, i+1], [j, j]], (nrow, ncol)))
        if rands[1] < p:
            edges.append(np.ravel_multi_index([[i, i], [j, j+1]], (nrow, ncol)))
        if rands[2] < 1 - (1 - p)**2:
            if rands[3] > 0.5:
                edges.append(np.ravel_multi_index([[i, i+1], [j, j+1]], (nrow, ncol)))
            else:
                edges.append(np.ravel_multi_index([[i, i+1], [j+1, j]], (nrow, ncol)))

    edges = [tuple(t) for t in edges]
    return pts, edges
```

Here is a sample output:

```
np.random.seed(333)
pts, edges = generate_graph(nrow=5, ncol=10, p=0.7)

print(f"sample vertex coordinates: {pts[:5]}")
print(f"sample edges: {edges[:5]}")
```

This gives:

```
sample vertex coordinates: [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0)]
sample edges: [(0, 10), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 2), (2, 11)]
```

Notice that unlike in the statement of the question, vertex coordinates do not include the vertex index, since vertices are already indexed by their positions in the `pts` list.

The next function plots the resulting graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_graph(pts, edges):
    fs = 10
    plt.figure(figsize=(fs, fs))
    plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
    for s in edges:
        plt.plot(*zip(pts[s[0]], pts[s[1]]), 'g-', alpha=0.5)
    plt.scatter(*zip(*pts), s=50, c='r', marker='o', zorder=10)
    for i, p in enumerate(pts):
        t = plt.text(*(np.array(p) + 0.1), str(i))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

For the graph created above we obtain:

```
plot_graph(pts, edges)
```

[image: plot of the graph]

The next function searches for colinear edges adjacent to a vertex. For a given graph vertex the function `colinear()` finds all edges that have this vertex as one of their endpoints, and returns a list of pairs of edges that are colinear. The search for the colinear pairs is done by first computing the angle between each edge and the positive x-axis, and then comparing angles for any two edges. Colinear edge pairs will have angles either equal or 180 degrees apart. The function takes three arguments: `center` is the index of the graph vertex to consider, `pts` is the list with graph vertices.`seg` is initially the list of graph edges - but more about it below.

```
def colinear(center, pts, segs, tol=10**(-9)):

    edges = [i for i in range(len(segs)) if center in [segs[i][0], segs[i][-1]]]
    if len(edges) < 2:
        return []
    vertices = [segs[i][1] if segs[i].index(center) == 0 else segs[i][-2] for i in edges]
    vects = np.array([pts[i] for i in vertices]) - np.array(pts[center])
    vects = vects[:, 0] + vects[:, 1] * 1j
    angles = np.angle(vects)
    dirs = np.abs(angles - angles.reshape(-1, 1))
    dirs = np.minimum(dirs, np.abs(dirs - np.pi))
    pairs = np.array(edges)[np.argwhere(np.tril(dirs < tol, k=-1))]
    pairs = [[segs[i][:], segs[j][:]] for [i, j] in pairs]
    return pairs
```

For example, we can find colinear edges adjacent to the vertex number 26:

```
colinear(26, pts, edges)
```

This gives:

```
[[(26, 35), (17, 26)], [(26, 36), (16, 26)]]
```

It means that the edges connecting vertex 26 to vertices 35 and 17 are colinear, and likewise for the edges connecting vertex 26 to vertices 36 and 16. A look at the plot above confirms that these are all pairs of colinear edges in this case.

The final function we need is `concat()`. For a given pair of paths (i.e. sequences of graph vertices connected by edges) that share one endpoint, it produces a new path joining the two paths together at the common endpoint.

```
def concat(pair):
    center = (set(pair[0]) & set(pair[1])).pop()
    new_pair = []
    for i in range(2):
        if pair[i].index(center) != 0:
            new_pair.append(pair[i][::-1])
        else:
            new_pair.append(pair[i][:])
    bds = [new_pair[i][-1] for i in range(2)]
    new_seg = new_pair[0][::-1] + new_pair[1][1:]

    if new_seg[0] > new_seg[1]:
        new_seg = new_seg[::-1]
    return new_seg
```

We can now find all paths in the graph consisting of colinear edges. The paths will be stored in the list `segs`. In the beginning, this lists consists of all edges of the graph. Then, for each graph vertex we find pairs of colinear paths adjacent to this vertex, and concatenate each pair to form a longer path:

```
segs = [sorted(s) for s in edges]
for i in range(len(pts)):
    colins = colinear(i, pts, segs)
    for pair in colins:
        new_seg = concat(pair)
        for i in range(2):
            segs.remove(pair[i])
        segs.append(new_seg)
```

At the end `segs` contains all maximally long paths consisting of colinear edges. Here is a printout showing all such paths consisting of et least 5 vertices:

```
for s in segs:
    if len(s) >= 5:
        print(s)
```

It gives:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41]
[8, 17, 26, 35, 44]
[6, 16, 26, 36, 46]
[8, 18, 28, 38, 48]
```

One can compare these results with the plot above.

**Adding distortion**

Next, lets create a graph where the grid of vertices is distorted to some extent:

```
np.random.seed(200)
pts, edges = generate_graph(nrow=5, ncol=10, p=0.8, distortion=0.2)
plot_graph(pts, edges)
```

[image: plot of distoted graph]

The function `colinear()` has a `tol` argument that can be used to add some tolerance to computations of colinearity of graph edges. However, the code as currently written will work only if `tol` is small compared to angles between edges. Changing this would require some modifications. In any case, lets apply this to the distorted graph, setting tolerance to 5 degrees:

```
tol = 5*(2*np.pi/360)

segs = [sorted(s) for s in edges]
for i in range(len(pts)):
    colins = colinear(i, pts, segs, tol=tol)
    for pair in colins:
        new_seg = concat(pair)
        for i in range(2):
            segs.remove(pair[i])
        segs.append(new_seg)
```

We can print approximately colinear paths of length are least 4:

```
for s in segs:
    if len(s) >= 4:
        print(s)
```

It gives:

```
[0, 10, 20, 30]
[4, 13, 22, 31]
[30, 31, 32, 33]
[35, 36, 37, 38]
```

**Final Note.** The above code can be optimized. In particular, it would be more efficient to use a dictionary recording which paths each vertex is an endpoint of, so that the function `colinear()` need not search for these path each time it is called.